What's the angle and weather conditions required for this to take place?
Sometimes when flying one can see this type of rainbow circle thing around the shadow of their plane.
Often the rainbow thing is projected onto clouds and then it contrasts and is visible clearly.
What's exactly the reason behind this type of artefact? I know how rainbows work but I didn't understand the circle rainbow around the shadow of the plane.
Is it only visible from some seats of the plane and not all?

